# Como mudar o layout cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, layout, view

Criei um layout para envio de newsletter, chamei de *email.ctp* e coloquei dentro do diretório **View/Layout**.
Minha dúvida é como eu uso esse layout ao invés do layout *default.ctp*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você necessitará usar `$this->layout = ...;` no seu `AppController`

Você pode usar:

```
public function beforeRender() {
    parent::beforeRender();

    $this->layout = 'layout_customizado';
}
```

Outro exemplo seria, aplicando um layout para cada "View" dentro do `AppController`

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    public function view_active() {
        $this->set('titulo_para_o_layout', 'Ver atividade dos usuários');
        $this->layout = 'layout1';
    }

    public function view_image() {
        $this->layout = 'layout_image';
        //Mostra foto do usuário
    }
}
```

Comment: No meu caso, utilizei o segundo exemplo

Comment: @Mathdesigner47 se funcionou, por favor marque a resposta como correta